# Problem with Chart Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am making a chart with the Chart Web Part of SharePoint 2010 Foundation, but I have the following problem, I have the following list with elements:

```
    Code    Product Sold         Date 
    1       Wood    $ 30000   01/01/2014 
    2       Leather $ 15000   06/01/2014 
    3       Wheat   $ 2500    06/01/2014 
    4       Fruit   $ 5500    01/11/2014 
    5       Wheat   $ 5500    01/11/2014 
    6       Fruits  $ 900     01/16/2014 
    7       Leather $ 90000   01/24/2014
```

How I can do with a cumulative total of graphic products?